# Split string without affecting the source

Tags: c, string, cstring, c-strings

How do I `strtok` filename so that the original string won't get affected?

```
void generate_header(int sock, char* filename, int response_code) {

  char buffer[BUFLEN];

  // For Content-Type generation                                                                                                   
  char *file_format;
  const char delimiter[2] = ".";
  file_format = strtok(filename, delimiter);
  file_format = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

  // Generate response code                                                                                                        
  /*
  ........ ommited ..........
  */

  // Generate Content-Type                                                                                                         
  if (strcmp(file_format, "html") == 0 || strcmp(file_format, "htm") == 0) {
    strncat(buffer, "Content-Type: text/html\n", sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1);
  }
  else if (strcmp(file_format, "txt") == 0) {
    strncat(buffer, "Content-Type: text/plain\n", sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1);
  }
  else if (strcmp(file_format, "jpg") == 0 || strcmp(file_format, "jpeg") == 0) {
    strncat(buffer, "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n", sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1);
  }
  else if (strcmp(file_format, "gif") == 0) {
    strncat(buffer, "Content-Type: image/gif\n", sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1);
  } else {
    strncat(buffer, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n", sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1);
  }

  // End                                                                                                                           
  strncat(buffer, "Connection: close\n", sizeof(buffer) - strlen(buffer) - 1);

  // Push                                                                                                                          
  write(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

Comment: why is there a `c++` and a `C` tag? which one is it? they are not the same?!

Comment: If you're using C++:  Use std::string, use find_first_of() in a loop, and forego the C stuff.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to get the file extension, isn't there a system function that you should use that does this already, without you using strtok?  Most, if not all of the major C++ (and even C) compiler libraries comes with such a function.

Comment: try --
`char file_name = [100]; strcpy(file_name, strtok(filename, delimiter));`

Comment: 1) Code's usage of `strlen(buffer)` after the `if()`s is bad.  `buffer` content is not set before the call.  2) `strncat(buffer, ...` is bad as in the following `strlen()` call in `// End ...  strlen(buffer) - 1)` does not guarantee that `buffer` ends in `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `strtok`, `strrchr` can find the last occurrence of the delimiter character:

```
if((file_format = strrchr(filename, '.')) == NULL)
    file_format = ""; /* no delimiter present */
else
    ++file_format; /* step over the delimiter */
```

Answer (score 0):

You copy it first. Then you run strtok on it which replaces occurrences of the delimter character with nulls.

If you want to get the parts of the string out without modifying the original, or copying it (I assume you want to copy the pieces into a destination string however) then you simply iterator over it until you reach the next delimiter, keeping track of the start and end positions and copy those.

You cannot point to the first half of the original string, and expect to get a partial result out without modifying or copying it.